# C# method setting variable to zero when it should not

Tags: c#

So I am supposed to make a method with a return value:

```
private decimal ReadInputThree()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ange valuta kursen:");
    decimal CurrencyValue = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return CurrencyValue;
}
```

And then using another method to use the CurrencyValue:

```
if (done == true)
{
    ReadInputTwo();
    ReadInputThree();
    Sum = Sum / CurrencyValue;
    Console.WriteLine("Värdet av valutan {0} är {1}", CurrencyName, CurrencyValue);
}
```

But when I run it, it tells me it can divide Sum with CurrencyValue, as CurrencyValue is set to 0. But how can that be? It should be whatever the user tells it to? I even wrote a WriteLine statement after ReadInputThree in the if statement to se if it would print the input string and it did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :** You are not holding the return value of the `ReadInputThree()` function.so value of `CurrenceyValue` variable stillbe Zero even after calling the `ReadInputThree()` function.

**Solution:**  You need to store the return value of the `ReadInputThree()` function  into `CurrencyValue`variable

Try This:

```
CurrencyValue = ReadInputThree();
Sum = Sum / CurrencyValue;
```

Comment: But I have done that? CurrencyValue is already an instance variable I have declared earlier.

Comment: @Baxtex: then just assign value to it,without declaring it. see my edited answer

Comment: @Selman22: yes right , i just created and assigned value because i didnt see anywhere he is declaring that variable in his code :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not assigning the result of `ReadInputThree` to `CurrencyValue`:

```
if (done == true)
{
    ReadInputTwo();
    CurrencyValue = ReadInputThree();
    Sum = Sum / CurrencyValue;
    Console.WriteLine("Värdet av valutan {0} är {1}", CurrencyName, CurrencyValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get return value from method. Also check for valid input and divide by zero exception.

```
private decimal ReadInputThree()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ange valuta kursen:");
    string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
    decimal CurrencyValue = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(userValue, out CurrencyValue);
    return CurrencyValue;
}

if (done == true)
{
    ReadInputTwo();
    decimal CurrencyValue = ReadInputThree();
    if (CurrencyValue != 0)
    {
        Sum = Sum / CurrencyValue;
    }
    else
    {
       Sum = 0;
    }


 Console.WriteLine("Värdet av valutan {0} är {1}", CurrencyName, CurrencyValue);
}
```